# Repeating a function throughout a dataset

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-2.7, numpy

I have been having trouble finding a solution to my problem.

I have a very large csv file containing multiple points. I have created two different functions that compute both distance and speed.

What I need is a way to carry out these functions between the first and second point, then the second and third point, and so on. I have been toying with using arrays and numpy, but I can not seem to figure it out.

Here are my functions:

```css
# distance
def haversine_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    degrees_to_radians = math.pi/180.0
    phi1 = (90.0 - lat1)*degrees_to_radians
    phi2 = (90.0 - lat2)*degrees_to_radians
    theta1 = long1 * degrees_to_radians
    theta2 = long2 * degrees_to_radians
    cos = (math.sin(phi1)*math.sin(phi2)*math.cos(theta1 - theta2) +
           math.cos(phi1)*math.cos(phi2))
    arc = math.acos(cos) * 6371  
    arc = arc * 1000 

    return arc
     
# speed 
def speed(lat1, long1, time1, lat2, long2, time2):
    distance = haversine_distance(lat1, long1, lat2, long2) 
    delta_time = time2 - time1 
    speed = (distance / delta_time) 
    speed = speed * 3.6 
 
    return speed
```

Comment: I should note that I am using python 2.7, any help would be great or even a point in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: can you show how you call speed?

Comment: Please post the code that reads the points and calls the speed and distance routines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can read your csv data into numpy arrays. Let's call them capital `Lat`,`Long` and `Time`. Then all you need to do is to call your functions over the appropriate points:

```
# initialize correct vectors
l1=Lat[:-1]      # all points but last
l2=Lat[1:]       # all points but first
lg1=Long[:-1]    
lg2=Long[1:]     
t1=Time[:-1]
t2=Time[1:]

speed(l1,lg1,t1,l2,lg2,t2)    # call the function which will run over your arrays
```